# Is there a way to tell if a Function returns a value?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Is there a way to tell if a function returns a value or returns void?

I've tried using describeType and this is what it returns:

```
<type name="builtin.as$0::MethodClosure" base="Function" isDynamic="false" isFinal="true" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Function"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="int" declaredBy="Function"/>
  <accessor name="prototype" access="readwrite" type="*" declaredBy="builtin.as$0::MethodClosure"/>
</type>
```

I've passed in both a function that returns a value and one that returns void. Both return the same XML value above.

Here are the functions and the code:

```
public function getElementCount(o:Object, count:String):String {

    return count;
}

public function getElementCount2(object:Object, count:String):void {

}

var o:Object = mx.utils.DescribeTypeCache.describeType(getElementCount).typeDescription;
var o2:Object = mx.utils.DescribeTypeCache.describeType(getElementCount2).typeDescription;
```

Comment: could you run a little bit of code that requests a return value and then tell whether or not it was expecting a value by the type of error that it throws?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `getQualifiedClassName(input)` with your function as input.

Example code :

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

    public class Get_Return_Type extends MovieClip 
    {

        public function Get_Return_Type() 
        {
            //# Check 1
            trace("check : function getElementCount");
            trace( "returns type : " + getQualifiedClassName( getElementCount(null, "test") ) );

            //# Check 2
            trace("check : function  getElementCount2");
            trace( "returns type : " + getQualifiedClassName(  getElementCount2(null, "test") ) );

        }

        public function getElementCount(o:Object, count:String):String 
        { return count; }

        public function getElementCount2(object:Object, count:String):void 
        { }


    }
}
```

**trace results :**

> check : function getElementCount
>
> **returns** type : `String`
>
> check : function  getElementCount2
>
> **returns** type : `void`